# ruby on rails: How to create table for a new model

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I use

```
rails generate model mynewmodel string:name string:description
```

to generate a new model. How do I deploy this new model to my develop databse ? I already have a bunch of databases in my sqlite  db.

I have tried

```
rake db:migrate
```

it seemed having trouble to generate this new table in db.

**update**: added error message

```
==  CreateMynewmodels: migrating ===============================================
-- create_table(:mynewmodels)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `name' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x3ad5c50>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Thanks

Comment: What you're doing is correct (`rake db:migrate`). We can't help without seeing error messages.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create` first?

Comment: @Casper no, i should run db:create before db:migrate?

Comment: Here's a good guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of your fieldname:type combo  is incorrect. Try

```
rails generate model mynewmodel name:string description:string
```

Comment: WOw. All of you were in a race apparently to answer this question.
You WON!

Answer (score 4):

The error in `rails generate model mynewmodel string:name string:description`

You should swap `string` and `name`

`rails generate model mynewmodel name:string description:string`

Answer (score 3):

Use `name:string` instead of `string:name` same for description

Answer (score 0):

Great article for advanced usage:
[Advanced Rails model generators](http://railsguides.net/2013/06/29/advanced-rails-model-generators/)

> Pay attention that you have to wrap parameter price:decimal{10,2} to
>   quotes. It's vital and you may have incorrect behavior of generator if
>   you don't do it.